# Looking for a Document Comparer that can generate difference reports

Tags: version-control, documentation-generation, merge-tracking

I've been using an application called "WinMerge" lately for document comparisons, but one of the requirements of my teams script files (for auditing purposes) is that when we release a revision of a script we highlight the changes in red (RTF format I believe, it's through Lotus Notes)  To that end, is there any software that can automatically highlight changes for me or is the best I'm going to get a list of differences and be expected to manually highlight all changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an HTML+CSS solution meets your needs, [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/convert-diff-output-colorized-html) from Linux Journal shows a shell script that reads diff output and writes an HTML document with colored text highlighting the differences.

On Windows, it would probably work as-is under bash as provided in the [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) environment from the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) folk or in bash from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). The script itself isn't too large, I would imagine it could be ported to Perl with only a moderate effort.

Since converting HTML to RTF turns out not to have a trivial solution that I've found, you might have better luck porting the script to directly output RTF.

Answer (score 1):

If an HTML report is acceptable, Beyond Compare can generate a comparison report that highlights differences. You can use the built-in stylesheets or a custom internal one to style the differences in red (the default is a light red color already).

It doesn't seem to be able to generate RTF, but perhaps there is a simple conversion between html/css and rtf.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of thing I was looking for, I appreciate the quick response Angela.